# Почему в интернете показан мой IP, а не IP роутера провайдера или крайнего роутера?

Tags: сеть

Я делаю запрос на myip.com. Он мне показывает IP, который назначен мне провайдером.

**Почему не так**:

Я делаю запрос на myip.com. Он мне показывает IP провайдера или крайнего роутера.

**Мои мысли:**

Когда я вбиваю myip.com, мне нужно сделать 2 вещи: узнать ip этого домена, а потом, грубо говоря, установить TCP соединение. Какой тут порядок? Я думаю +- так:

1. Система ищет у себя в кэше инфу про myip.com
2. Там ее нет, она что? Отправляет DNS пакет моему провайдеру? А основной пакет, пока никуда не идет (GET myip.com)?
3. DNS: Resolver -> ROOT -> Namespace server и обратно ко мне.

На данном этапе провайдер знает, что я делал DNS запрос по myip.com. Идем далее:

4. Теперь зная IP, мой комп отправляет пакет (с dst ip `myip.com` и MAC моего роутера) на мой роутер.
5. Мой роутер отправляет пакет на роутер провайдера (с dst ip `myip.com` и MAC роутера провайдера)

На этом этапе провайдер знает куда я собрался, ну и если нет шифрования, то знаеет вообще все.

Соответственно, src ip будет всегда меняться на ip предыдущего роутера. И когда мой GET дойдет до myip.com в source уже должен быть IP моего провайдера или вообще предыдущего роутера. Отсюда у меня возникают два вопроса:

1. Правильно ли что, сначала уходит чисто DNS запрос, а HTTP никуда не идет?
2. Каким образом myip.com умудряется узнать мой IP? Ведь там в запросе в src должен быть IP пред роутера?

Пока писал вопрос, пришла мысль, что network layer вообще не трогается, а меняется всегда только MAC? Но если network layer не трогать, то как VPN умудряется его изменить?

Пожалуйста, помогите. Что-то я совсем запутался.

Comment: «показывает IP, который назначен мне провайдером» — это просто значит что провайдер выдаёт вам «белый» IP. Всё.

Comment: «Соответственно, src ip будет всегда меняться на ip предыдущего роутера» — с чего бы?

Comment: И можете проверить счет за интернет, не переплачиваете ли. Что-то я сомневаюсь, что вам "белый" адрес бесплатно дали.

Comment: @Сергей, почему нет? обычно платные _статические_ ip, которые постоянны, бесплатны динамические, которые могут меняться при переподключении

Comment: @Grundy, а, ясно, спасибо. Вы имеете в виду, что он "белый", но не статический. Да, не учел,что и так бывает.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Что всё? Конечно мне провайдер выдает белый IP, как иначе я бы получил доступ в интернет? Через NAT. "С чего бы" - именно это я и спрашиваю.

Comment: «Конечно мне провайдер выдает белый IP» — не конечно. Мне вот выдаёт «серый» `10.17.33.107`. И myip.com показывает другой IP. src ip меняется на NAT-ах (ну или если специально заморочиться), в остальных случаях он летит дальше как есть.

Comment: У меня провайдер выдает статический белый IP без какой-либо дополнительной платы. С момента подключения 7 лет назад он ни разу не менялся.